# Laravel 5.8: How to pass two arguements to Event & Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-events

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have created an Event called `UserWalletNewTransaction` that goes like this:

```
public $transaction;
public $added_type;

public function __construct($transaction, $added_type)
{
    $this->transaction = $transaction;
    $this->added_type = $added_type;
}
```

As you can see I have specified two parameters here and these parameters are getting their value from the Controller:

```
event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction, $value_added_type));
```

And then the Listener which is named `UserWalletNotification` goes like this:

`public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event, $added_type) {`

But there is something wrong here, since I'm getting this error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Listeners\UserWalletNotification::handle(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

So how to fix this issue? How can I pass two parameters to Event & Listener properly?

---

### Update 1

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UserWalletNewTransaction event:

```
public $transaction;
public $added_type;

public function __construct($transaction, $added_type)
{
    $this->transaction = $transaction;
    $this->added_type = $added_type;
}
```

which you can call like this `event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction, $value_added_type));`

and UserWalletNotification listener:

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event)
{
    $transaction = $event->transaction;
    $added_type = $event->added_type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.

```
event(new UserWalletNewTransaction([ 'transaction' => $newTransaction, 'added_type' => $value_added_type));
```

```
public $transaction;
public $added_type;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->transaction = $data['transaction'];
    $this->added_type = $data['added_type'];
}
```

UPDATE #1:

You should remove 2nd argument of handle function. You can access `added_type` data in `$event` variable.

Comment: Again `Too few arguments to function App\Listeners\UserWalletNotification::handle(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected` !! There is something wrong with `public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event, $added_type) {` at the Listener

Comment: Maybe you have to post handle function code.

Comment: It's empty. I just added an **UPDATE #1** to question.